# Regex: Finding strings that doesn't start with X

Tags: regex

I am completely hopeless with regular expressions...

I have a Velocimacro named `#addButton`, and I have a JS function named `addButton()`. Now I want to find all the places the JS function is called. So I need to search for "addButton", where "addButton" **doesn't** start with the hash key.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
/([^#]|^)addButton/
```

It will match every string where "addButton" is *not* preceded by "#" or the beginning of the string.

Comment: Or to make it a little more robust (so that it will match at the beginning of a string), `/(?:^|[^#])addButton/`

Comment: awesome! ... I think I should invest some time in regex...it just keeps popping up everywhere...

Answer (score 24):

I don't know what Velocimacro is (judging from the other answer I guess "addButton" will appear on its own line?), but the sure-fire way of finding the word "addButton" that is not preceeded by `#` is the following:

```
/(?<!#)\baddButton\b/
```

It will:

1. `(?<!#)` [(?)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

   - Make sure that the current position is not preceeded by a `#` (hash mark)
2. `\b` [(?)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

   - Make sure that the current position is a word boundary (in this case it makes sure that the previous character is not a word character and that the next character is)
3. `addButton` [(?)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

   - Match "addButton"
4. `\b` [(?)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

   - Make sure that there is a word boundary at the current position. This avoids matching things like "addButtonNew" (because there is no word boundary between "addButton" and "New")

A difference with this regular expression and the other is that this one will not consume the character before "addButton".

A good resource for learning about regular expressions is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Click the (?) link in the list above for a link to the relevant page for that part of the regex.

Comment: excellent informative answer. thanks! (: I was just doing a regex search in Eclipse, so consuming characters doesn't matter. (btw, Velocimacro is sorta like a function in Velocity (open source templating language), and you call them like normal functions, only every command in Velocity starts with the hash key)

Comment: Thanks, how can I say "Don't match #, including if followed by any number of spaces?"