# javascript regex match ^[^#]?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm searching a regex in js to match string doesn't start with #
the opposite of this function

```
   String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
        return this.match(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g);
    }

    t="#lorem #ipsum yes no";
    console.log(t.parseHashtag()); // ["#lorem", "#ipsum"]
```

I found this [Regex: Finding strings that doesn't start with X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264571/regex-finding-strings-that-doesnt-start-with-x)

but the regex doesn't work /([^#]|^)[a-z]/ or maybe I'm tired… 
I do a replace() but really be curious to understand how to do it in match()!

Here is a js : http://jsfiddle.net/d8HVU/1/

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Which regex doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and is working well for Javascript on your sample input. I hope it is also ok for other inputs. Test it well. The other answers did not work out in Javascript.

```
String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
    return this.match(/(\s|^)[^#][\w\d-_]+\b/g);
}

t="#lorem #ipsum yes no";
alert(t.parseHashtag());
```

Comment: +1 probably you are right and this matches the best what OP wants. 2 small things, it will match the whitespace before the word (I think no chance to avoid this, cause Javascript does not support lookbehinds), second no need for `\d` in the charclass, its included in `\w`.

Comment: Oh, and an important point: escape the dash in the character class or move it to the end it defines a character range (maybe not needed because before is a predefined class, the `\d`).

Comment: (\s|^) I need to learn regex… 
^ is for start or  'not' when it's in [] ? but don't know when is single with | (it's OR ?)…
regex is the new sudoku for webdev…

Comment: Yes, all right. | is or. Like stema said, maybe you also have to escape the dash, I'm not an expert for JS regexes. I tried to keep as much as possible from your original regex.

Answer (score 1):

Non-`#` character followed by anything:

```
[^#].*
```

See it working at http://refiddle.co/1rj

Answer (score 0):

If I was trying to match the last hash tag and all chars that follow it, I'd use this regex:

```
/#[^#]*$/
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nE2bM/

If you're trying to do something different, please clarify exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead for this

```
^(?!#).*
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30738)

This matches each string that does not start with a "#".

OK, I am not sure, do you want to match the start of the string or kind of a "word" that does not start with "#"?